# How to get all tweets containing a certain username or name

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, twitter, tweepy

I am writing a code using the tweepy library to collect all tweets containing a specific user id. For this example let's say I want to find all tweets related to [Austrian Airlines](https://twitter.com/_austrian)

What I would do to achieve such goal (assuming I have access to the twitter API) is something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import API
from tweepy import Cursor

auth = OAuthHandler(twitter_credentials['CONSUMER_KEY'], twitter_credentials['CONSUMER_SECRET'])
auth.set_access_token(twitter_credentials['ACCESS_TOKEN'], twitter_credentials['ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET'])
api = API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True,wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

# Search word/hashtag value 
HashValue = '_austrian'
# search start date value. the search will start from this date to the current date.
StartDate = "2019-11-11" # yyyy-mm-dd

for tweet in Cursor(api.search,q=HashValue,count=1,lang="en",since=StartDate, tweet_mode='extended').items():
    print (tweet.created_at, tweet.full_text)
```

However this approach doesnt seem to return what I expect. I just get a series of tweets where the word austrian is mentioned.

What should i do in order to get just the tweets containing _austrian?

Comment: Do you get different results when searching on the website? I wonder if punctuation in search terms is simply ignored.

Comment: @larsks well i do not search to other websites currently because my goal is jut to use twitter. if you mean other accounts i tested with ScuderiaFerrari and seems to work... my goal is to get all tweets where the item _austrian is present.

Comment: I mean if you search *using the twitter website* does `_austrian` produce different results from `austrian`.

Comment: @larsks good observation... yes, if i type on the search bar of the website i do get stuff which i am not interested in!! how do i solve this?

Comment: @larsks btw i tried to add also the @ in front of _austrian  so that i am looking for @_austrian but still i get additional tweets which are not related at all

Comment: I'm not an authority here, but it looks as if you can't get the results you want from the twitter api. You may have to take the list that includes everything containing the search term without punctuation and then filter it locally to eliminate tweets in which you are not interested.

Comment: Looking at the standard operators https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/rules-and-filtering/overview/standard-operators

I think if you combine the `@`, `to:`, and exact quote `""` operators, you may be able to get what you're looking for. I would try `HashValue='"@_austrian"'` first. If not, I think @larsks is right, and you'll have to filter after searching.

Comment: Ok thank you guys! Tomorrow i will give it a shot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is use this package instead: [GetOldTweets3](https://github.com/Mottl/GetOldTweets3)

I used the following code.

```
tweetCriteria = got.manager.TweetCriteria().setQuerySearch('@_austrian')\
                                       .setSince("2019-11-11")\
                                       .setMaxTweets(10)
tweet = got.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)
```

Currently, its set to look for all tweets that contains '_austrian' with a given date and is limited to 10 tweet searches on the code. Adjust according to your needs.

To loop through the results you'll need to for loop it.

```
for item in tweet:
  print(item.username, item.text)
```

Sample Output

```
HofmannAviation In the 1980s I joined a #tyrolean Airways Dash 7 pilot training flight to Courchevel in the French Alps. In the Cockpit also Armin Kogler @_austrian @AHoensbroech @Flugthier @AlexInAir @_ABierwirth_ #dash7 @courchevel @BBD_Aircraft @GabyAttersee @AgueraMartin @GuillaumeFaurypic.twitter.com/NULpX4WSkA
```

You can read more on the github page on how you can control the searches. You can get more than the usernames and the content using this package.